# Finding lexicographically numbers with a defined amount

Tags: sorting, lexicographic

I am struggling to achieve a solution for the following problem.

Imagine that I have 6 candies, and i have to give these candies amount 6 children where none of them can have more than 2 candies.

Example:
000222
121020

What i need to achieve is find all possible solutions in a lexicographically order, so for the same example as above it would start like.

000222
001122
001212
001221

I wrote an algorithm to create a base solution that would give me the first lexicographically solution (in the example above it would give me the result 000222) and then i wrote another algorithm that would always find me the next solution in the lexicographically order, so if i sent 000222 to this algorithm it would give me 001122.

My problem is that my algorithm is not working properly, the way i wrote it when it needs to something like this:

```
console.log(nextSchedule("001221"))
```

It would give me 002121, when the correct answer would be 002022. I understand why my algorithm is doing that but i don't know how to improve so it can handle these cases.

I am sending my nextSchedule algorithm as the way it is now.

Can someone give me some kind of direction to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

```
function nextSchedule(currentSchedule) {
    let newSchedule = currentSchedule.split('');
    for (let i = newSchedule.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (newSchedule[i] > newSchedule[i - 1]) {
            newSchedule[i]--;
            newSchedule[i - 1]++;
            break;
        }
    }
    newSchedule = newSchedule.join('');
    return newSchedule === currentSchedule ? null : newSchedule;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: imagine your goal was to produce all possible numbers 000000 through 222222, where each digit can only range from 0 to 2. Your method would do this by taking the input number, then adding 1 to the rightmost digit. If the result is higher than 2, wrap it around to 0 and carry over the 1 to the digit immediately to the left. Repeat until there is no carry over.

(This is just like you'd add two numbers on paper, except you stop at 2 instead of 9.)

However, you now have an additional constraint: you only want numbers where there are a total of six candies given out (ie: the sum of all digits in the number is 6). So, add that check in - if the "next" number doesn't add up to 6, then just keep repeating the process until you find one that does.

Basically, you'll loop through all 729 6-digit base-3 numbers, but toss out the ones that don't meet your criteria.

Comment: That would definetly work, thank you very much for your suggestion! I am still thinking for a way to create only valid numbers so it would be more efficient. If i end up not finding a way to achieve this i will go for your suggestion. Again thank you very much!